# Typescript is not bundling angular2 and rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outFile": "./js/app.js",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [ "node", "core-js" ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./ts/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is my `system.config.js` (Basically nothing)

```
System.import('main');
```

What I am doing is, I want to bundle everything into one JS file so that I can use it for production. TypeScript did most of the steps for me. It bundles all my scripts into one `app.js` files.

However, I got

```
http://localhost/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic 404 (Not Found)
```

on my browser console.

After digging into the `app.js` I discover that, all @angular and Rxjs code are not in the bundled file. So SystemJs does not know how to look for them and request the script files in the default way.

My understanding is, in `tsconfig.json` the line `"moduleResolution": "node",` is already telling TypeScript to load @angular and Rxjs by the "Node way" which should mean go to `node_module` to load those dependencies, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is just a language compiler,not a module bundler. You want to use webpack , browserify or rollup for that task.

To clarify an usual workflow wit webpack would be

TS > es6 > babel > webpack > bundle

I don't know how systemjs works, but you don't want to use bundling capabilities of typescript if you need to bundle extra stuff. You would have to rely on another module bundler for that task, and leave typescript doing what it does best: compiling typescript code.

A webpack rules example would be as follows. Note that webpack applies the loaders under use in reverse order, so the ts-loader is executed first

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,

                use: [{loader:'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['es2015'], plugins: ['add-module-exports'] }},'ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: If this is true, how supposingly do we use TypeScript with SystemJs? It means, TypeScript `"module": "system"` outputs files which cannot be used standalone in production environment. It needs some other way to bundle packages from `node_modules` into SystemJs format. If my statement is true, what is the common tool for the task?

Comment: Another question is, if TypeScript and SystemJs makes bundle separately, how does SystemJs know what packages are needed to be bundled? Say I installed `lodash` in my `node_modules` but it is not used by all of my TypeScript. Will the SystemJs bundle also include it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did not solve this question directly. I notice there is a better way to deal with Angular2 using [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) which is sort of official way to build an Angular2 project. And I am not using SystemJS anymore.

The little problem of using SystemJS is that it is not supported by Webpack. It means it cannot be used in Angular CLI.

Danielo is true that TypeScript is not a module bundler. However, I based on my understanding of TypeScript, they are moving to support all needs in the field including being a module bundler which might not supported so well at the moment.